# How to get temperature of datetime value based on the table which contains day and night wise temperature data

Tags: excel, datetime, vlookup, temperature

I have data of temperature in a table which shows the temperature of day time(09:00-21:00) and night time(21:00-09:00) for 15 days. I want to get the temperature for any datetime value based on the table I have.

The table data is like this [image]

I want to know the temperature for a particular date time value
[image]

I have tried to use vlookup function =*VLOOKUP(A2,F1:H31,3,0)* in B2 cell   but it does not helped me. I have attached file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OiYbL_5vauJb_a0ViF7bOyoF_bTKf_yx/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: `=VLOOKUP(A2,$F$1:$H$31,3,TRUE)`

Comment: @Axel both are same, in vlook up for exact match we can use 0 or TRUE

Comment: No, `TRUE` is **not** exact match. You cannot use exact match since nothing matches exactly in your case. Simply try `TRUE` in your formula.

Comment: I guess this vlookup function won't work, instead of this we can check the date time is falling between From and To then extracting the value of temperature is the logic that I am looking. So the value **02-02-2019 00:34** falls between **01-02-2019 21:00** and **02-02-2019 09:00** and the corresponding temperature value 7.5 should come in the cell B2.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `MAXIFS` to find the temperature where your specified datetime falls between the "from" and "To" values:

```
=MAXIFS($H$2:$H$16,$F$2:$F$16,"<" & $A2,$G$2:$G$16,">=" & $A2)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gravitate

Comment: @Sivakesav No problem. If it solved your problem, please accept it as the answer. If you are still having problems, please let me know so that I can help further.